# Plain Javascript Swipe Event on html..?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, swipe

I want to implement swipe functionality using plain java Script for my responsive project.. i followed this [tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents3.shtml)... 
I am unable to implement that.. events are initiated correctly but won't works whether mobile and system browser..

**My Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #touchsurface2{
            height:200px;
            width:300px;
            background-color:#ffce44;
            border:1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
    <script> 
    function ontouch(el, callback){

    var touchsurface = el,
    dir,
    swipeType,
    startX,
    startY,
    distX,
    distY,
    threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
    restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
    allowedTime = 500, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
    elapsedTime,
    startTime,
    handletouch = callback || function(evt, dir, phase, swipetype, distance){}

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        dir = 'none'
        swipeType = 'none'
        dist = 0
        startX = touchobj.pageX
        startY = touchobj.pageY
        startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
        handletouch(e, 'none', 'start', swipeType, 0) // fire callback function with params dir="none", phase="start", swipetype="none" etc
        e.preventDefault()

    }, false)

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        if (Math.abs(distX) > Math.abs(distY)){ // if distance traveled horizontally is greater than vertically, consider this a horizontal movement
            dir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right'
            handletouch(e, dir, 'move', swipeType, distX) // fire callback function with params dir="left|right", phase="move", swipetype="none" etc
        }
        else{ // else consider this a vertical movement
            dir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down'
            handletouch(e, dir, 'move', swipeType, distY) // fire callback function with params dir="up|down", phase="move", swipetype="none" etc
        }
        e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
    }, false)

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
        if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ // first condition for awipe met
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
                swipeType = dir // set swipeType to either "left" or "right"
            }
            else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
                swipeType = dir // set swipeType to either "top" or "down"
            }
        }
        // Fire callback function with params dir="left|right|up|down", phase="end", swipetype=dir etc:
        handletouch(e, dir, 'end', swipeType, (dir =='left' || dir =='right')? distX : distY)
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
}
</script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
         var el = document.getElementById('touchsurface2')
         ontouch(el, function(evt, dir, phase, swipetype, distance){
             var touchreport = ''
             touchreport += '<b>Dir:</b> ' + dir + '<br />'
             touchreport += '<b>Phase:</b> ' + phase + '<br />'
             touchreport += '<b>Swipe Type:</b> ' + swipetype + '<br />'
             touchreport += '<b>Distance:</b> ' + distance + '<br />'
             el.innerHTML = touchreport
         })
        }, false);
</script>
</head>
 <body>
 <center>
    <div id="touchsurface2">
    </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I want use the event swipe on mouse in web browsers and touch in mobile browers

Can anyone please give the solution..
*THANKS IN ADVANCE*

Comment: Simply add the event listeners for mousedown/mouseup to it...

Comment: @Jonas w got it.. thank you so much